How can I automate echo-tee-i2c?
The problem
I use Xubuntu LTS 24.04 LTS.I installed ddcci_dkms to control brightness but had to run the following command to make it work:
$ echo 'ddcci 0x37' | sudo tee /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-2/new_device
$ xfce4-panel -q
$ xfce4-panel

(I didn't run xfce4-panel -r because it doesn't work well for some reason.)
So now I can adjust brightness, but I need to run it every time I boot my machine.Is there any way to make it run automatically when I log into a session?I googled a ton and thought there would be some way implement echo-tee-ish thing in a simple systemctl service or something, but I don't have any knowledge about systemd, udev or whatsoever and I'm at a loss what to do.
What I tried but to no avail:
I tired a solution given in the link below, but that came with another problem; it's slow to be loaded.When I type my password in my startup screen fast and log in quickly, the systemctl is not loaded and therefore doesn't allow me to adjust brightness.When wait on a login screen and type the password slowly to log in, I see a brightness adjustment bar and can actually control it.
https://gitlab.com/ddcci-driver-linux/ddcci-driver-linux/-/issues/7#note_151296583
(I ran ddcutil detect --verbose to find out my i2c number was i2c-2)
/etc/udev/rules.d/99-ddcci.rules:
SUBSYSTEM=="i2c-dev", ACTION=="add",\
        ATTR{name}=="i915 gmbus dpc*",\
        TAG+="ddcci",\
        TAG+="systemd",\
        ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="ddcci@i2c-2.service"

/etc/systemd/system/ddcci@i2c-2.service:
[Unit]
Description=ddcci handler
After=graphical.target
Before=shutdown.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo Trying to attach ddcci to %i && success=0 && i=0 && id=$(echo %i | cut -d "-" -f 2) && while ((success < 1)) && ((i++ < 5)); do /usr/bin/ddcutil getvcp 10 -b $id && { success=1 && echo ddcci 0x37 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/%i/new_device && echo "ddcci attached to %i"; } || sleep 5; done'


I'm unfamiliar with what Xubuntu uses as a desktop manager (LightDM?) however I would slip this between graphical.target and whatever DM is being loaded. If it was LightDM, that would mean replacing Before=shutdown.target with Before=lightdm.service (otherwise just replace lightdm.service appropriately), so that the scipt would finish executing before you even see the DM's interface.

https://www.malibal.com/guides/how-to-run-a-script-at-startup-on-linux/ ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29247942/3776858 ?

@Cyrus Not that simple, the thing needs to run after the driver is loaded and before the DE is started to work consistently. Some basic grasp of systemd (or ability in leveraging the DM pre-script) is required to make it run exactly when it has to.

/etc/systemd/system/ddcci@i2c-2.service ... that doesn't look right. It should be just /etc/systemd/system/ddcci@.service service - the @ indicates a template and systemd will replace %i in the service with the part that follows the @, but the original template itself shouldn't have anything after @.

@kos Yes Xubuntu comes with LightDM.I tried Before=lightdm.service but didn't make it work well.I do agree with the point that it should theoretically be executed right before LightDM service though.

@Cyrus I tried working on the problem that way at first, but as kos pointed out, the command needs to be run after ddcci_dkms is loaded.

@muru The original file does have a name of ddcci@.service, and I did change it for my environment; i.e. ddcutil detect --verbose showed i2c-2 is what ddcci_dkms needs to detect, so should it be in the file name.Actually I ran an original ddcci@.service at first, but I got an error message to suggest it must have a value after @ symbol.

@BehdadB the filename is supposed to be just ddcci@.service. That's how templates work in systemd. It's when you use that service elsewhere (e.g., in the udev rule, or when running systemctl start <service>, or in journalctl -u <service>) that you use ddcci@<whatever>.service.). But not in the original filename itself.

@muru I just tried it, and surprisingly the result was exactly the same; it's available when I wait for several seconds and slowly log into a session, and not when I type my password fast and log in quickly.I thought sleep=5 was something prohibiting ddcci from activating snappily and changed it to sleep=1, only to find out nothing changed.

In either case(whether the file name is ddcci@.service or ddcci@i2c-2.service), when I log into a session quickly, it's not activated but will be activated later.That is to say, if I wait for over several seconds after login and restart xfce4-panel by running "xfce4-panel -q" and "xfce4-panel", I can see brightness controller that surely works (again, there's no need to run those commands when I log in slowly).Maybe ddcci is such a thing that takes a long time to be loaded, but I'm not quite sure.

What do you mean "it didn't work well"? Same as before? Or what happens?

@kos It just didn't make ddcci-dkms work at all.In other words, I couldn't see brightness controller no matter how slowly I log in.

By the way, I've come to wonder the root cause of this problem might be partly related to the fact I use a relatively low-end computer, which is what Xubuntu is not responsible for.

Right, sorry for the tentative approaches, I'm not really familiar with the chain of dependencies here, nor I ever fiddled too much with udev in general; what I'd try next would be to override LightDM's unit file (see this excellent answer by muru) in order to inject / change a After dependency in order to make it depend on the actual device unit generated through udev (systemctl list-units --ty=device to find out the actual name). Also note that muru is right, the name of the unit file shouldn't include the parameter

@kos I've looked through that detailed instruction by muru.However, it's beyond my knowledge as a layperson, and I might want to try to get along with the current situation, which only costs me deliberate slow login at boot.So thank you all for helping me out and I'll mark this solved now(I think I need to upvote instead of saying thank-you, but I'm not allowed to do that now probably because I don't meet the criteria, say, like I don't make enough amounts of posts/edits or whatever).
